# emacs 24.3 from http://emacsformacosx.com/ cannot export html after upgrading org-mode to org-version-8.2.1-15

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

What I did:
emacs 24.3 for OS X was downloaded from http://emacsformacosx.com/, which comes with bundled org-mode version 7.9.3f.

I upgraded org-mode by following the method from here:
http://orgmode.org/manual/Installation.html#Installation
with the method#1 Using Emacs packaging system.

I included (package-initialize) in my .emacs profile.

Problems:
I no longer can run org-babel
C-c, C-e, b to export selected portion for html export.

When I run C-c C-e h h, it says "Invalid Key"

When I run M-x org-publish-project , it says "Invalid function: (......)".

Can anyone can shed some lights on the problem?

Comment: Try to uninstall Org and quit Emacs.  Then start Emacs, and **before** opening any Org file, install the new Org.  Then restart Emacs again, and try to export again.

Comment: How do I cleanly remove all bundled org-package without any side-effect?

Comment: Don't.  You should never remove built-in libraries.  Just remove the one that you have installed yourself via package.el.

Comment: I just removed ~user/.emacs.d/elpa. Then did exactly what you said. The M-x org-version says 8.2.1. However, after that, I still cannot export org files to html. org-babel did not work neither.

Comment: I encountered a similar problem and had to comment out anything in my init.el / .emacs that loaded org stuff in order to install the org package from elpa, and then re-enable the org stuff after the install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh!

The HTML export problem can be solved if I simply remove
(require 'org-publish) for org-version 7.x.x, and replace it with
(require 'ox-publish) for org-version 8.x.x at the very top of my .emacs file.

Why the didn't the official site just say so? D'oh!

As of 2013 Oct 31, the babel problem is still unsolved as babel site mentions that it is integrated in org-version 7.x.x but does not mention anything about 8.x.x. (see http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/). Is there anyone using the bleeding edge version of babel with org-version 8.x.x without problem?